# javascript library to decrypt a 3des file

Tags: javascript, encryption, 3des

I have a base64 encoded string that contains a **3DES** encrypted png file. I need to show this image on the client side provided the right password is given by the client.
I have been searching for some *crypto library* with this functionality but could not find any (or at least none with some documentation or examples).
I know of many nice libraries that support AES encryption, but ATM my input is 3des encrypted and I can't change that.
Could someone point me to a library with built in 3des decryption ? Also an example would be great.

Answer (score 0):

So I did the Google search for "javascript 3des" for you. Here's the first result.

http://etherhack.co.uk/symmetric/des_3des/

(JS: http://etherhack.co.uk/symmetric/des_3des/js/dessrc.js)

How this works on binary data is another question - how do you store the binary data in your JS right now anyway?

Comment: I found this link myself the first time I googled, unfortunately, this resource lacks any form of documentation, and I am having a hard time understanding how the function works. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [jscryptolib](http://code.google.com/p/jscryptolib/)? They provide:

- Symmetric encryption: AES, DES, 3DES
- Encryption mode: ECB, CBC, CTR
- Digest algorithm: SHA-1, SHA256
- Message Authentication Code (MAC): HMAC, CBCMAC, CMAC
- Random number generator (RNG): FIPS186, X9.17
- Public key cryptography: RSA, DSA, ECC, CPK, IBE

It's LGPL licensed, so you should not have problems using it on your project.

Comment: This is what is stated on the front page but I have yet to find any piece of code that relates to 3des encryption. And since there is no documentation for it and the fact that there is an empty `des.js` file makes me believe this library is not complete. I could be wrong ...